# AWS XRay latency filter

Tags: aws-xray

Doing anything wrong here?
Response time should be in specified range, but results are different:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see where I am wrong. That's a response time that is outside my range is a response time for the whole trace, not a segment. And my filter is applied to segment response time (there was also a `service(SNS)` element in a query that was not captured in a screenshot). If I click that trace I can see that the specified segment indeed has response time in specified range.

Comment: The response time if a trace is the response time of the root segment(segment without parent_id). Is that the case in your data? If that is not the case, can you please share the trace json with me and I can look deeper.

Comment: @RohitBanga yes, you are right. that's the response time for the root segment.